# Android Studio Table Layout

Tags: android, android-studio

Hey everyone I'm trying to make a table for my app that lists the newest apps we updated. I want this table to have 3 columns and 4 rows. The first box will start with a green color with opacity at %100. Then each box after that will be the same green color but just subtracting opacity by %12. How am I able to achieve this? Thanks for your help. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdoX2.png) is included for an example of what I would like to do in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Paramount TPA]

```
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="IRDA Primary Code "
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Particulars"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Amount Claimed"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="100000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Room Nursing Charges"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtDetailsOneId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="2100"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="200000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="ICU Charges"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4500"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="300000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="OT Charges"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="31000"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="400000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Medicine Consumables charges"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="3310"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="500000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Professional fees charges"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="262686"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="600000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Investigation Charges"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="4550"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="800000"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Miscellaneous charges"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="350"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Total Claimed Amount:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/black" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="308496"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Explain your answer